# Truffle verify - Cannot find module '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol'

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, chainlink

Currently i am working an a small dynamic nft example. Compiling, Deploying and to fund the [Contract](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xfbf0c9f50cd04a167ff4287bf8439006eb4c670c) works well.

If i try to verify the contract with truffle and the truffle-verfiy-plugin, I got the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle-plugin-verify/verify.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/original-require/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
Failed to verify 1 contract(s): DynamicNft
```

This are the modules, I am importing in my contract:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
```

My package.json-dependencies looks like:

```
    "@chainlink/contracts": "0.0.8",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^3.1.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.40",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
```

And at least the command I run for the verification:

```
truffle run verify DynamicNft --network kovan --license MIT
```

[The contract](https://github.com/KevvKo/dynamic-nft-example/blob/main/contracts/DynamicNft.sol)
Has anybody an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you run `npm install truffle-plugin-verify` ?

Comment: yep, is already installed.

Comment: Did you deploy the contract?

Comment: Did you read the entire post? Yes, it is deployed. See above the contract.

Comment: I mean to the same network

Comment: Ah ok, everything is deployed in the testnet kovan

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is something up with the verifier and multiple versions of solidity... might be good to get an idea of what your contract looks like

Comment: Is the file named DynamicNFT or the contract itself?

Comment: But your getting an error with it finding the chainlink packages, but yet you can deploy it? That’s odd....

Comment: I attached the contract code at the bottom of the question. Yes, I can deploy it but with the verify-plugin, it tells me the chainlink module is not available.

Answer (score 2):

After a research in the chainlink-docs, I find a solution.
I added the following to the devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/belt": "^0.0.1",
    "@chainlink/test-helpers": "0.0.5",
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.6",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "depcheck": "^0.9.1",
    "solhint": "^2.1.0",
    "truffle": "^5.1.5",
    "truffle-plugin-verify": "^0.5.7"
  }
```

installed it again with npm install and tried it again:

```
kevin@kevin-desktop:~/websites/html/dynamic-nft-example$ npm run verify

> dynamic-nft-example@1.0.0 verify
> truffle run verify DynamicNft --network kovan --license ISC

Verifying DynamicNft
Pass - Verified: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xFbF0C9F50cd04a167FF4287BF8439006EB4c670C#contracts
Successfully verified 1 contract(s).
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls try like this:

```
npm install -g @chainlink/contracts truffle-plugin-verify
```

and then

```
truffle run verify DynamicNft --network kovan
```

I hope it works for you.